# Lambda function C3923 error in CLR (Windows Form)

Tags: c++, lambda, compiler-errors, clr, windows-forms-designer

I need to call a 'test' function, sending a class member function 'curve' in it, when the button of Windows Form is pressed. This code worked in CLR console application, but when dealing with Windows Form, I get a C3923 compiler error (local class, struct, or union definitions are not allowed in a member function of a managed class) and 'a local lambda is not allowed in a member function of a managed class type' is highlighted. How to solve this problem?

Header file "calculus.h":

```
#pragma once
#include <functional>

class A
{
public:
    double r;
    double curve(double x);
    A() { r = 0.0; };
};

class B
{
public:
    double z;
    B() { z = 0.0; };
};

B test(std::function<double(double)> f, double y);
```

CPP file "calculus.cpp":

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "calculus.h"

double A::curve(double x)
{
    return x + r;
}

B test(std::function<double(double)> f, double y)
{
    B* result = new B();
    result->z = f(y);
    return *result;
}
```

Part of a Windows Form file "Form1.h":

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
{
    A t;
    B r = test([t](double double_) mutable { return t.curve(double_); }, 2.0); // C3923
}
```

Comment: Your `new B` in the `test` function will lead to a *memory leak*. If you want to use C++/CLI and .NET managed objects you need to use `gcnew` and reference-counted pointers using `^`.

Comment: Okay, but when I tried ```gcnew``` and ```^``` with lambda function, it gave me even more errors. Anyway, it does not solve the problem

Comment: To be honest, I don't really see the need for dynamic allocation of the `result` object at all. As in `B result; result.z = f(y); return result;`

Comment: When dealing with operator overload for '+,-,*,/', the absence of dynamic allocation caused some errors for me during program execution. The new class simply was not created and the program terminated, though there were no compiler errors. So after that I decided to allocate memory dynamically everywhere when I need to create and return a new class.